# Is there a way to disable accessibility font scaling for a UITableViewRowAction button?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need a way to disable font scaling for a UITableViewRowAction button. Is there any way to either just disable font scaling or get access to the UITableViewRowAction button itself so I can change it's font size?

I've already tried accessing the button inside of the editActionsForRowAt function and the didTransition(to state: function inside of the UITableViewCell's class by stepping through the subviews.

```
override func didTransition(to state: UITableViewCell.StateMask) {
    super.didTransition(to: state)
    if (state.rawValue & UITableViewCell.StateMask.showingDeleteConfirmation.rawValue) == UITableViewCell.StateMask.showingDeleteConfirmation.rawValue {
        let deleteButton: UIView? = subviews.first { (view) -> Bool in
            return String(describing: view).contains("Delete")
        }
        if let deleteButton = deleteButton {
            print(deleteButton)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to access the TableViewRowAction button. If you subclass UITableView and override layoutSubviews then you can use this loop to find the UIButton.

override func layoutSubviews() {

```
    super.layoutSubviews()
    for subview in subviews {
        if NSStringFromClass(type(of: subview)) == "UISwipeActionPullView" {
            for case let button as UIButton in subview.subviews {
                button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
            }
        }
    }
}
```